# Help with linked lists in c#

Tags: c#, linked-list

How can I know if this code is from a **Single Linked** List?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

// T is the type of data stored in a particular instance of GenericList.
public class GenericList<T>
{
    private class Node
    {
        // Each node has a reference to the next node in the list.
        public Node Next;
        // Each node holds a value of type T.
        public T Data;
    }

    // The list is initially empty.
    private Node head = null;

    // Add a node at the beginning of the list with t as its data value.
    public void AddNode(T t)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.Next = head;
        newNode.Data = t;
        head = newNode;
    }

    // The following method returns the data value stored in the last node in
    // the list. If the list is empty, the default value for type T is
    // returned.
    public T GetFirstAdded()
    {
        // The value of temp is returned as the value of the method. 
        // The following declaration initializes temp to the appropriate 
        // default value for type T. The default value is returned if the 
        // list is empty.
        T temp = default(T);

        Node current = head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            temp = current.Data;
            current = current.Next;
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Each node contains a link to the next node in the list. That's why it's called a **linked** list.

```
private class Node
{
    // Each node has a reference to the next node in the list.
    public Node Next;
    // Each node holds a value of type T.
    public T Data;
}
```

It is a **single linked** list because there is no `Previous` (and no `tail`). So the list can only be traversed in one direction. To make a **double linked** list you would do something like:

```
private class Node
{
    // Each node has a reference to the next node in the list.
    public Node Next;
    // Each node has a reference to the previous node in the list.
    public Node Previous;
    // Each node holds a value of type T.
    public T Data;
}
```

And add a `tail` to the List class. Make sure to link to the previous item correctly when you operate on the list. The add method then becomes:

```
// Add a node at the beginning of the list with t as its data value.
public void AddNode(T t)
{
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.Next = head;
    if (head != null) {
        head.Previous = newNode;
    }
    newNode.Data = t;
    head = newNode;
}
```

You can now traverse your list in two directions. And adding items at the end performs better since you don't have to traverse the whole list to get to the tail item.

Answer (score 0):

**Singly-linked** lists contain nodes which have a data field as well as a next field, which points to the next node in the linked list.

In a **doubly-linked** list, each node contains, besides the next-node link, a second link field pointing to the previous node in the sequence. The two links may be called forward(s) and backwards, or next and prev(ious).

[image: doubly-linked list]

Apparently your code is singly linked list